# Add to ThreadPool while its running

Tags: java, threadpoolexecutor

I currently use a ThreadPoolExecutor inside of a SwingWorker so that I can display a ProgressBar.

'Tasks' are added to ThreadPool and then I kick off the Swingworker which executes the ThreadPoolExecutor and monitors its progress.

My 'Tasks' can generate other 'Tasks' that also need to be ran. I'm trying to wrap my mind around how i could submit the new Tasks to the ThreadPool and still track the progress.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

> I'm trying to wrap my mind around how i could submit the new Tasks to the ThreadPool...

That part's easy.  Just add 'em.

> ... and still track the progress.

I'm guessing that, at minimum, you want the progress to be a montonically increasing function of time.  Only way I can think of is to structure your tasks in such a way that you can first do a "dry run" that just counts them, and then you do the *real* run which actually performs the tasks.

Comment: Why not create one thread to monitor the Pool and update the progress bar. Other tasks can still be submitted to the ThreadPool and run normally?

Comment: @MinhKieu The question is a little thin on details, but it sounds like the OP is saying he wants each task to be a unit of progress, but he doesn't know in advance how many tasks will be needed.  If the code simply bumps up the `progressBar.setMaximum(n)` each time it discovers a new task, that likely would make the progress bar go backward.  If it goes backward, the user will not be able to guess how long the whole process will take, and that defeats the purpose of showing a progress bar.

Comment: That is correct. What is the best way to account? I'm taking a snapshot of a network device. The network device may contain 'virtual devices' which will also need to have snapshots taken. No way to know in advance if and how many snapshots are going to be taken.

Comment: @JamieSnipes I don't know.  If you can't count the tasks in any less time than it would take to _do_ the tasks (e.g., if just enumerating the devices is the full extent of the work), then I'd be looking at some other way of diverting the user's attention instead of using a linear progress bar.  Maybe something as simple as showing a running count of "devices found so far" in a dialog box.